# Excluding non-relevant parameters when using PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords

Tags: python-3.x

In an embedded python scenario we are using `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` to receive data from Python (version >=3 .x) and use it in a C++ application.

At the moment we have a similar setup:

```
PyObject* whatever(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds) {
    ....
    static char* kwlist[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL };
    ...
if(!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, ..., kwlist, ...))
    {
        ...bail out
```

however, if we pass more parameters than the two expected (e.g. issuing a python call like `whatever(foo="a", bar="b", baz="c")`) the whole thing crashes (not really, it returns an error, but that's beyond the scope here).

We would like to avoid such scenarios; it would be great if we could parse *only* the parameters in the `kwlist` and ignore everthing else. What's the best way to do it?

One solution we were thinking about was to convert `kwlist` into a `dict`, then manipulate it with `PyDict_Merge` or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end we solved it like below:

(I'm answering my own question since nobody answered, and I think it might be valuable to somebody else in the future).

```
PyObject* whatever(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *incoming_keywds) 
{

    static char* kwlist[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL };

    PyObject* keywds = PyDict_New();
    /**
     * The following routine returns a subset of the incoming dictionary 'incoming_keywds'
     * containing only the keys allowed in the list 'kwlist'
     */
    for ( int i = 0 ; kwlist[i] != NULL ; i++ )
    {
        char* key = kwlist[i];
        PyObject *single_key = Py_BuildValue("s", key);
        if ( PyDict_Contains(incoming_keywds, single_key) )
        {
            // not checking for NULL as GetItem return value since
            // we already checked above if the dict contains key 'single_key'
            if ( PyDict_SetItem(keywds, single_key, PyDict_GetItem(incoming_keywds, single_key)) < 0 )
            {
                /* error */
            }
        }
        Py_DECREF(single_key);
    }
    /** end */
```